# Property of Zero element in factor ring

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to learn proof for "Let R be a commutative ring with unity and let A be an ideal of R.Then R/A is an integral domain if and only if A is prime".
In first part of proof in text book I see this statement: [image]

MY PROBLEM IS: 1:Why ab is the zero element of the ring R/A? 
2:I'm confused with properties of "general" R/A ring, what is similar and not similar to the factor groups?
IMPORTANT NOTE: I have read lots of similar related topics but there wasn't any helpful or explanation about my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a set, $R/A = \{a + A \big| \ a\in R \}$, the set of equivalence classes modulo $A$. Now, the zero of the ring $R/A$ is the equivalence class of $0_R$ ie $0_R + A$, but  $0_R + A = A$. That's why the author of this proof says that "$A$ is the zero element of the ring $R/A$.
2. Quotient groups and quotient rings work alike. The difference is that while you quotient groups by normal subgroups, you don't quotient rings by rings but by ideals instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because $ab \in A$ we have $ab + A = 0 + A$ in $R/A$, and $0 + A$ is the zero element.

The ring $R/A$ is exactly a factor group.  The ring $R$ under addition is an abelian group called the additive group of $R$.  The ideal $A$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $R$.  Since the additive group is abelian all subgroups are normal, so the factor group $R/A$ exists.  This factor group is the additive group of the ring $R/A$, in fact the construction of the ring $R/A$ is done by defining a multiplication operation on this factor group.